# Editable Button

Tags: wpf, xaml, view

I have a datagrid with two column. first one is the button ID, the second one is button label.
For the buttonLabel column i want them to have the appearance of a "button", when the user click on it, it will enable an edit mode.

This is what i have right now:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,3,0,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto">

                    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              Height="Auto"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=States}"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              CanUserAddRows="False"
                              Focusable="False"
                              CanUserSortColumns="True"
                              KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue"
                              EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                              EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                              SelectionMode="Extended"
                              >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Id" Width="*" MinWidth="100" 
                                        ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Path=Id}">

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Margin="1" Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Label" Width="*" MinWidth="100" 
                                        ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Path=Label}">

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                                            <Button x:Name="textBlock" Margin="1"
                                                Content="{Binding Path=Label}"
                                                Foreground="{Binding Path=ForegroundColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter}}"
                                                Background="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter}}"/>

                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Label, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                        </TextBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

The issue i have with this code is when user want to edit the content of button, he will need to click on the "edge" of the cell to enable the edit mode.

[image]

How should i modify it so when the button is clicked the edit mode will be enable right away? 
(FYI i have a same implementation in the application where i used textblock instead of button, and it works perfectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option one: Set the IsHitTestVisible property to false on the button.

Option two: Make the TextBlock look like a button by copying the XAML from the Button template.

Comment: thank you so much!! by setting the isHitTestVisible makes it worked just the way i needed